# What's up with the Marine uniforms in this episode of Scorpion?

Tags: scorpion

In the  *Scorpion*, episode, "Once Bitten, Twice Die," Latvian and Belarussian diplomats come to America to hash out a peace treaty and avert World War III. The stuff about Walter and a possum getting bit by a snake so a doctor can use a centrifuge and make the antidote seemed very silly to me.

But what I'm taking issue with is the U. S. Marine's dress uniforms. Instead of the eagle, globe and anchor on their caps, you see on the various *NCIS* shows (when they have actual Navy/Marine Corps characters, that is) and the old *JAG*, they have an upside down five-painted star!

Does this mean that *Scorpion* takes place in a parallel universe in which the Marines decided they preferred a generic star to be their logo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They didn't have a military advisor and they had no help from the Department of Defense. It's possible that the producers wanted to shield the actors from being prosecuted for impersonating a military servicemember, but given that *Scorpion* is on the same network that now airs a bunch of *NCIS* shows, *Scorpion*'s producers ought to know better.

It seems more likely to me that the costume designer thought the star looked cooler and failed to realize the significance the eagle, globe and anchor holds for anyone who's ever served in the Marine Corps.

http://www.stripes.com/blogs/the-rumor-doctor/the-rumor-doctor-1.104348/why-can-t-hollywood-get-military-uniforms-right-1.159651

Answer (score 0):

I think the developers did it just for fun. Or, what if it is in the future where they change the corps uniform. It could be that.

Comment: This answer is pure speculation. Do you have any references to cite?

Comment: This is more suited to be a comment.